# jQuery ev.preventDefault not letting "a" tags to fire

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using preventDefault to stop a click of an "a" tag to scroll back up to the top of the page. On the flip side I get no response from my "a" tags if I have the .preventDefault() coded in the jQuery. Maybe you guys can be of assistance?

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="Community">
    <br/>
    <ul id="commlinks1" class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked col-md-12">
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.facsniagara.on.ca/" target="_blank">FACS Niagara External Website</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.fccniagara.on.ca/" target="_blank">Family Counselling Centre</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/AboriginalServices/Home.cshtml" target="_blank">Aboriginal Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://bethlehemhousing.ca/" target="_blank">Bethlehem Place</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.camh.net" target="_blank">Centre for Addiction and Mental Health website</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.chs.ca/" target="_blank">Canadian Hearing Society</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.cfshw.com/" target="_blank">Catholic Family Services of Hamilton</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.contactniagara.org/" target="_blank">Contact Niagara</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.dsbn.org/" target="_blank">District School Board of Niagara</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://elishahouse.on.ca/" target="_blank">Elisha House</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked col-md-12" id="commlinks2">
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.informationniagara.com/" target="_blank">Information Niagara - Helping Through Information</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.informationniagara.com/interpreters-niagarahamilton/" target="_blank">Interpreters Niagara-Hamilton Service</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.neighboursfriendsandfamilies.ca/" target="_blank">Neighbours Friends and Families</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.niagarahealth.on.ca/en/mental-health-addictions" target="_blank">New Port Centre</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.niagaracatholic.ca/" target="_blank">Niagara Catholic District School Board</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.niagarahealth.on.ca/" target="_blank">Niagara Health System</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.niagararegion.ca/" target="_blank">Niagara Region</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.breastfeedingniagara.ca/" target="_blank">Niagara Region Breastfeeding Coalition</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.nrh.ca/index.html" target="_blank">Niagara Regional Housing</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.niagarapolice.ca/en/index.asp" target="_blank">Niagara Regional Police Service</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked col-md-12" id="commlinks3">
        <li>
            <a href="http://niagarasuicideprevention.weebly.com/" target="_blank">Niagara Suicide Prevention Coalition</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://nss.ntec-nss.com/page/home" target="_blank">Niagara Support Services</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.parentdirectniagara.ca/" target="_blank">Parent Direct Niagara</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://www.sixnations.ca/LandsResources/ContactUs.htm" target="_blank">Six Nations Contact Information</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="http://womensplacestcatharines.ca/" target="_blank">Women's Place - Services for Abused Women</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="pagination">
        <ul class="pager">
            <li id="comm1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li id="comm2"><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li id="comm3"><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jQuery:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#commlinks1").show();
    $("#commlinks2").hide();
    $("#commlinks3").hide();

   $("#comm1").click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $("#commlinks1").show();
        $("#commlinks2").hide();
        $("#commlinks3").hide();

    });
    $("#comm2").click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $("#commlinks2").show();
        $("#commlinks1").hide();
        $("#commlinks3").hide();

    });
    $("#comm3").click(function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        $("#commlinks3").show();
        $("#commlinks2").hide();
        $("#commlinks1").hide();

    });
});
```

It's using bootstrap paging. If I take out preventDefault, tabing and clicking works perfectly fine, just have the hasle of it scrolling back to the top of the page.

Comment: That's what `preventDefault` is supposed to do. Why do you want external links to scroll down the existing page?

Comment: use `return false` instead of `preventDefault()`

Comment: I've used return false, same result. Also its BOOTSTRAP PAGING, when clicking on a number to navigate through pages it scrolls to the top. External links don't even fire, actually nothing works when I have return false or preventDefault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change

```
<li id="comm1"><a href="#">1</a></li>
```

to

```
<li><a id="comm1" href="#">1</a></li>
```

If not work, let me know.

Comment: I think that the problem is not with ev.preventDefault(), because I have the following code:`$( '#link' ).click( function( e ){
  e.preventDefault();
  $( '#button' ).click();
 } );`


and it works to me...

Answer (score 1):

Well `.preventDefault()` does what it says, and it prevents **all** default behavior. However for an `<a>` tag it's pretty easy to simulate the native behavior.

```
$("ul a").click(function(e) {
  window.location.href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try `javascript:void(0);`

Comment: same result thanks though. It might be something else in thecode.